# Data table sorting issue (wants the default sorting not active when page loads first time)

Tags: jquery, datatables

I used datatables in my project. I want to disable the default sorting of datatable and the server side sorting to be executed when page loads first time. Every thing is fine, I has also given ("aaSorting": [],) empty as directed but still i am not getting the correct results. 
What I am missing, please help me!

Answer (score 2):

use bSort property to enable or disable sorting feature

```
"bSort": false
```

for example

```
$(document).ready( function () {
      $('#example').dataTable( {
      "aaData": [
                ['Trident', 'Internet Explorer 4.0', 'Win 95+', 4, 'X'],
                ['Trident', 'Internet Explorer 5.0', 'Win 95+', 5, 'C'],
             ],
       "sPaginationType": "full_numbers", 
        "bSort": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "iDisplayLength": 20,

      } );
    } );
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response EOF. I also tried that but still not getting required structure. this is my code  $(document).ready(function() {

      $('#example').dataTable( {
      "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
      "aaSorting": [],
      "bSort": false,
      "bAutoWidth": false,
      "iDisplayLength": 20,

      });
});
</script>

Comment: @asim Can I get your entire .dataTable(.....) code??? I mean the properties of datatable;

Comment: how you are passing aaData??

Comment: Check in Firebug whether tabledata are added to HTML or not

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {

      $('#example').dataTable( {
      "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
      "aaSorting": [],
      "bSort": false,
      "bAutoWidth": false,
      "iDisplayLength": 20,

      });
});

Comment: Yes datatable is added to the html it is okay on column wise sorting. mean pagination and other things are fine

Comment: then ( "bSort": false ) should work. Don't know how its nt working in your code...

Answer (score 0):

If you want that your data will not sort by datatable functionality then just disable sorting
by this little code.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  $('#example').dataTable( {
    "bSort": false
  } );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your good efforts. I changed the looping condition and giving "aaSorting": [], in jquery ready function and all it works good.